# How to select correct capture group within regex OR?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Let's say I am given a list of names (first + last). I want to match all middle names that are surrounded by a first + last name from the list. Right now, in Python, my regex pattern string is:

`regex_str = "|".join([r"\b%s\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+%s\b" % (first_name, last_name) for (first_name, last_name) in names])`

For simplicity's sake, let's say `names = [("John", "Smith"), ("Jane", "Doe")]`. Then, we would have `regex_str = "\bJohn\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+Smith\b|\bJane\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+Doe\b"`

Now to go through a string and change all instances of "first middle last" name to simply "middle" for all "first last" pairs in my list (e.g. "John Jack Smith" should be replaced with "Jack"), I attempted

`re.sub(regex_str, r"\1", input_str)`

This however only works for the very first name in the list (John Smith). I quickly realized this was because if it actually matched to any other name in the list, the capture group would have a different index, like `\2` for the second name. Is there a way to make the capture group grab the corresponding middle name while still using regex's OR matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `OR`, regex will match either
the first part, hence the first group `\1`, leaving `\2` empty OR
the second part, hence the second group `\2`, leaving `\1` empty.
So you can use both group on your code to substitute like the following:

```py
re.sub(regex_str, r"\1\2", input_str)
```

Comment: This is nice, but what happens if my `names` list has more than 99 names? I think `\99` is the largest it can get.

Comment: Yea, I know. This is just a workaround. Not sure if there is a dynamic way.

Comment: you can use `\g<number>` to get past `99` groups.. only reason `\100` and above don't work is because for whatever reason, Python wanted `\0` and 3-digit escapes to indicate octal format.. but they do not allow hexadecimal and unicode escapes (unless you use string instead of raw-strings, in which case you'll have to use ``\\`` to indicate ``\``  metacharacter)